# URLs ending with number higher than 2147483647 redirects to to domain.com/2147483647

Tags: url-rewriting, javascript, redirect

I've got a javascript implented on my Wordpress site with the purpose to the substring of the URL and if it matches some criteria, it'll load a specific piece of content.

So, if you input this URL for example `http://domain.com/subpage/84708495222` it should catch `84708495222` and find the content associated with this number. This works as intended.

BUT, the problem is that Wordpress for some reason redirects `http://domain.com/subpage/84708495222` into `http://domain/subpage/2147483647`. I guess it's due to some sort of rewriting mechanism in Wordpress. Is there some way to avoid this?

`84708495222` in this example is not generated by me, and cannot be changed to a lower number..

Comment: What is this (84708495222) number?

Comment: It's a reference to a Tumblr post. The purpose with the whole thing is that the javascript checks the URL for a valid reference, if it's found, the content of the Tumblr post is fetched via ajax, so the number needs to be intact..

Comment: How is `subpage` set up?

Comment: `subpage` is a page. Merely a placeholder actually, I created it because I got 404 (the data on `subpage`is fetched via javascript aswell)

Comment: I think you need an [endpoint](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=endpoint).

Comment: @s_ha_dum Hm, is the purpose of an endpoint that it's "outside" Wordpress? I.e. it doesn't apply rewrites and acts more like a standalone page?

Comment: The purpose of an endpoint is to have a page that acts as a kind of placeholder for dynamic URLs so that WordPress knows what to do the address.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Alright. But I'm still curious how to apply it. Since 84708495222 is just an example. How do I catch any other case? I noticed most examples talks about /subpage/<catcher>. Where catcher is static. Btw `/subpage/9999` and `/subpage/omg` is not redirected. Leads me to think it's more about Wordpress not being able to handle large ints? https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16445

Comment: `2147483648` is redirected, but not anything beneath.

Comment: Are you doing _nothing at all_ with rewrite, just append the number to a normal page URL? The behavior would not be defined if the URL structure doesn't match anything in rewrite.

Comment: `subpage` would be the "catcher" address.

Comment: @Int you are correct, the maximum value for a LONG is between -2147483648 and 2147483648.  See The [Wikipedia Entry for Integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)).Save the TumblerID as a STRING, then send the STRING to the catcher.

Comment: I think the problem is that Wordpress(?) intercepts and redirects before I can do anything at all, let alone saving the Tumblr post id via `window.location.pathname`...

Comment: Deleted the page named "subpage" and it's now working as I want (no redirect).